# firebase / how i can to get a field from all doc's in firestore / javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

strucrure 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFaND.png)

I need to get data from the "Income" field, which is in each  document in collection "values", and write them to array to calculate the sum of the elements of this array.

Comment: What part of this task are you having problems with?  Do you have any code to share that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson  write to array and calculate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as follows if you want to sum up the values. You don't need an array.

```
var totalIncome = 0;
db.collection("values").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        totalIncome += doc.data().Income;
    });
    console.log(totalIncome);
});
```

Be aware however that it will cost a document read for each document of the collection. If your `values` collection contains a lot of documents, you may use another strategy like updating the totalIncome on documents creation/deletion.

If you really need to populate an array, do as follows:

```
var totalIncomeArray = [];
db.collection("values").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        totalIncomeArray.push(doc.data().Income);
    });
    //Do whatever you want with the array: it contains all the Income values
});
```